# How to obtain the marginal effect for a panel data logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, panel-data

I have a panel data logistic regression model and I would like to produce the marginal effects for those estimates.
the model is estimated using `pglm()` from `pglm` package as below.

```
library(pglm)
Model2 <- pglm(AidDep~Infl + I_GDP + I_S_GDP + FDI_GDP + GDP_G,
               na.action=na.omit, data = P_DF, 
               family = binomial(link = "logit"), model = "random")
```

If it were a glm model I could have just used

```
library(margins)
margins(Model2)
```

however in the case of `pglm` the function produces error

```
Error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component nor attribute") : 
  no terms component nor attribute
```

Is there any existing package that I can use to perform such task?

Comment: I do not believe that any of the existing `R` packages that compute marginal effects currently support, or are likely to support `pglm` models (ever). The fundamental problem is that the `pglm` package does not supply a `predict()` method, so external `R` packages cannot use numeric differentiation to compute marginal effects. FYI, I ran into this issue when I tried to add support for `pglm` in the [`marginaleffects` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/), which is like `margins` but supports more model types.

Comment: @Vincent thanks for your feedback, is there any alternative package for estimating panel glm that would allow computations of marginal effects?

Comment: No, sorry I don't, but I would be curious to know if you every find one.

Comment: I guess stata will be the only way to go

Comment: If you're leading just looking for a random effects model, the `lme4` package and `glmer` function might work.